# Nth not recognized PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I've been dealing with lists in SICStus Prolog 4.3.0 (latest version) and I have the need to print an element of a list which Index is N.

I made some research and the predicate `nth` seemed to be the one:

```
nth0(?N, ?List, ?Elem)
```

I gave it a go and tried it out but apparently the predicate is not recognized anywhere:

```
| ?- nth0(3, [a, b, c, d, e], Elem).
! Existence error in user:nth0/3
! procedure user:nth0/3 does not exist
! goal:  user:nth0(3,[a,b,c,d,e],_217)
```

Any suggestions on what is going on?

Edit: I looked up the documentation for SICStus 4.3.0 and the predicate does exist. It just won't be recognized.

Edit2: I tried adding the lists library `: :- use_module(library(lists)).` Still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I figured it out myself.

[Edit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747613/nth-not-recognized-prolo) was the answer, but it was not correctly implemented. It should be used as follows:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
```

Comment: Why is this not correctly implemented? The code line you show here is the way in which you would typically import a Prolog module. Notice that in some Prolog implementations often-used modules are loaded automatically, which may be one of the reasons why some people skip explicit module imports in their code.

Comment: @WouterBeek If you take a look at Edit2, you will notice an extra ":". I ran the code with and without the colon and it only worked fine in the answer I provided.

Comment: Ah, you mean that your own use of `: :-` was incorrect. To that I agree.

Comment: I assume you entered `:- use_module(library(list)).` at the toplevel. There, it should be `use_module(library(list)).` alone. Only within a file/module the directive with `:-` is valid.

Comment: If you are happy with your own answer, you can accept it (klick on the checkmark - it will turn green!).